# Alarm Manager does not works properly

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Alarm Manager does not works properly, as sometimes it triggers the alarm at rigth time but sometimes it triggers alarm after a delayed time of 2-5 minutes and some times it even not triggers the alarm

```
public static void setAlarmTime(Context context, String userName, String selectedRitual,int dayOfWeek, int hourOfDay, int minute, int rStamp, boolean isUpdate) 
 {
     Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
     cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
     cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
     cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
     cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

     long alarmTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    Intent intent= new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppsConstant.SELECTED_RITUAL, selectedRitual);
    intent.putExtra(AppsConstant.user_name, userName);
    intent.putExtra("alarmTime", "day"+dayOfWeek+" hour"+hourOfDay+":"+minute);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    if(!isUpdate)
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), rStamp, intent, 0/*PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT*/);
    else
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), rStamp, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);

  //check whether the time is earlier than current time. 
    if(cal.before(now))
    {
        alarmTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()+(alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7);
    }
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, alarmIntent);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using [setInexactRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), which, by documentation, does not always trigger at exactly the time given:

> Schedule a repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements;
>   for example, an alarm that repeats every hour, but not necessarily at
>   the top of every hour.

If it does not trigger at all when you think it should, consider that you might be rescheduling an existing alarm for the future in some cases.

Comment: I have replaced the setInexactRepeating to setRepeating but still it behaves similar to earlier